# How to unmerge multiple cells and transpose each value into a new column in Pandas dataframe from Excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

This has 4 to 5 merged cells, blank cells. I need to get them in a format where a column is created for each merged cell.

Please find the link for Sample file and also the output required below.

#### Link : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fkG9YT9YGg9eXYz6yTkl7AMeuXwmNYQ44oXgA8ByMPk/edit?usp=sharing

Code so far:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('/Users/john/Desktop/Internal/Raw Files/Med/TVS/sample.xlsx',sheet_name=None, header=[0,4], index_col=[0,1])

df_2 = (pd.concat([df.stack(0).assign(name=n) for n,df in dfs.items()])
          .rename_axis(index=['Date','WK','Brand','A_B','Foo_Foos','Cur','Units'], columns=None)
          .reset_index())
```

How do I create multiple column in the above code? Right now I'm getting the below error:

```
ValueError: Length of names must match number of levels in MultiIndex.
```

Comment: what is d expected output?

Comment: I have mentioned in the required output in the sheet shared, with the sheet called "output"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
df = pd.read_excel("Sample_File.xlsx", header=[0,1,2,3,4,5], index_col = [0,1])
df.stack(level=[0,1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. Just one query, this will ignore the cells which are empty right for that particular date say?

Comment: i dont think it should, if it does, you can add `dropna=False`

Comment: okay will try it